# Py2neo - Rollback to previous state

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I need a way to reach a previous state of the graph (i.e undo X number of changes).

Is it possible to store the data, so that later you can replace the graph by that copy? Or is it possible to export the graph to a file and then load a graph from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three possible ways of doing it, completely independent of py2neo :

**Method 1: Simple copy of the store files :**

```
cp -R data/graph.db data/backup
```

**Method 2: Run the backup command :**

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/backup-embedded-and-server.html

```
mkdir /mnt/backup/neo4j-backup
./bin/neo4j-backup -host 192.168.1.34 -to /mnt/backup/neo4j-backup
```

**Method 3: Run the *experimental* Cypher dump command :**

Create a dump of your db

```
./bin/neo4j-shell -c 'dump MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() RETURN r,n' > export.cql
```

For reimporting your graph, drop your db with Cypher, then :

```
./bin/neo4j-shell -file export.cql
```